# How to configure full screen MenuAnchor width

Tags: flutter, width

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97wEp.jpg)

I want to use MenuAnchor to display a down box with the width of the screen. How to configure it

I've been looking at the code, the screen configuration widget set the widget to double.infinity and still can't fill the screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.